# Python. Построение графика по точкам из ком-порта в режиме реального времени

Tags: python, serial, многопоточность, runtime

Задача в следующем:
необходимо написать программу которая будет читать значения из ком-порта и строить по ним график в режиме реального времени. Кое-как реализовал, НО получается задержка минимум в 3-4 секунды.

Пришел к выводу, что не успеваю забирать значения из буфера. Можно рисовать график в несколько потоков, но поскольку в питоне я не силен. Обратился к вам.

Пожалуйста, предоставьте примеры многопоточного рисования графика с подробным описанием.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

class SerialRead():
    com = 0

    def __call__(self):
        import serial
        self.com = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 1200)

    def readValue(self):
        #import time
        #time.sleep(0.2)
        #self.com.flushInput()
        ERR = False
        try:
            line = self.com.readline()
        except:
            ERR = True
            print("ERR::Ресурс временно недоступен!")
        if ERR != True:
            try:
                value = float(line)
            except:
                print("ERR::Wrong value at serial port!")
                ERR = True
        if ERR != True:
            return value


c = SerialRead()
c()

class DynamicUpdate():
    #Suppose we know the x range

    min_y = 0
    max_y = 5.1

    def on_launch(self):
        import numpy as np
        #Set up plot
        plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

        self.figure, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.lines, = self.ax.plot([],[], 'r')
        #Autoscale on unknown axis and known lims on the other
        #self.ax.set_autoscaley_on(True)
        #self.ax.set_xlim(self.min_x, self.max_x)
        self.ax.set_autoscaley_on(True)
        self.ax.set_ylim(self.min_y, self.max_y)

        #Other stuff
        self.ax.grid()
    ...

    def on_running(self, xdata, ydata):
        import numpy as np
        #Update data (with the new _and_ the old points)
        self.lines.set_xdata(xdata)
        self.lines.set_ydata(ydata)
        #Need both of these in order to rescale
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()
        #We need to draw *and* flush
        self.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.figure.canvas.flush_events()
        #########################################
        x = max(xdata)
        if x > 10000:
            self.ax.set_xlim(x, x - 10000)
        else:
            self.ax.set_xlim(0, x)
        #########################################

    #Example
    def __call__(self):
        import numpy as np
        import time
        import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
        import random
        self.on_launch()
        xdata = []
        ydata = []
        while True:
            OLD_VALUE = c.readValue()
            xdata.append(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
            ydata.append(OLD_VALUE)
            self.on_running(xdata, ydata)
            #time.sleep(1)
        return xdata, ydata

d = DynamicUpdate()
d()
```

Comment: Я, конечно, не сильно в курсе, но: не упираетесь ли вы просто в производительность самого Python'а?

---
Попробуйте попрофилировать. Если bottleneck — рисование, может быть, стоит не вызывать `on_running` на каждом пришедшем фрагменте данных? (Операции наподобие `autoscale_view` или `flush_events` не выглядят исходя из названия очень уж дешёвыми.)

Comment: @palyla: Я не уверен, что многопоточность поможет, если bottleneck'ом является скорость расчётов. В Python (по крайней мере старых версий) использовалась глобальная блокировка, которая по сути блокировала одновременную работу нескольких потоков. Возможно, @jfs сможет лучше прояснить ситуацию.

Comment: @palyla: Ну хорошо. Попробуйте тогда обновлять рисунок не каждый раз, а лишь каждые, допустим, 10 значений. Вы ведь всё равно не дополняете данные, и перерисовываете «с нуля», верно?

Comment: @palyla: Не-не, вы ж запоминаете все значения в `xdata` и `ydata` в любом случае. Так что вы не пропускаете _значения_, вы пропускаете слишком частые обновления картинки.

Comment: @palyla: Хм. Подождём экспертов по Питону. Если скорости отрисовки не хватает, возможно, вам либо нужна другая графическая библиотека, либо другая платформа.

Но вы всё же попробуйте поэкспериментировать с пропуском вывода. 10 мс — это быстрее, чем человек воспринимает. Вам с головой достаточно 25 fps = 40 мс на обновление.

---
У вас вышел лимит комментариев, удаляйте старые.

Comment: @palyla, а какая реальная скорость порта (и формат сырых данных)?

Кстати, просто для эксперимента, попробуйте получится ли просто читать и печатать их (без всякого графика, просто печатать последнее из накопленных значений) на питоне.

Comment: @palyla, т.е. у Вас около 200 чисел в секунду. Может имеет смысл писать это в файл и выводить график с нужной скоростью ("замедленное кино" или "ускоренная съемка" или как это называют?).

--

По поводу обсуждения (лимита комментариев).

Наверное можно сделать свой фиктивный ответ и дальше отвечать в нем, постоянными **update**.

Comment: @palyla, да, с Вашим взглядом на систему общения здесь я солидарен, а вот со взглядами на файл и многопоточность (независимо от питона или др. языка) -- нет.

Файл (в \*nix (а у Вас скорее всего Линукс)) это тот же буфер в памяти (кэш), а на синхронизации потоков при такой гранулярности Вы все потеряете.

У Вас могут быть 2 процесса, один (примитивно cat > file & ???) пишет, а другой с нужной частотой читает из файла новые числа и рисует новый кадр, возможно отображая сразу несколько точек.  
(я давно не рисовал, но если это сделать с двойной буферизацией прямо на Xlib, то ...)

Comment: @avp, Спасибо за совет. Так и сделаю. Только вот я никогда не рисовал с двойной буферизацией прямо на Xlib)) 
Если есть возможность, пожалуйста приведите примеры.

Comment: @palyla, использовать напрямую Xlib это, конечно же, шутка (программа получится слишком объемной). 

Эта библиотека что-то вроде ассемблера (если проводить аналогии между языками программирования) для оконной графики в \*nix. Нижний уровень взаимодействия с сервером графики. Она лежит где-то в глубине почти всех библиотек, которыми все обычно пользуются (а двойная буферизация там может в каком-то из виджетов и неявно присутствовать).

Comment: Попробуйте graphite для отрисовки графиков. Зачем изобретать велосипед, тем более, если сидите под линухом. Для той же убунты это несколько вызовов apt-get install.
И тогда Вы точно не будете тратить время процесса на отрисовку. При наличии всего одного ядра - графит можно развернуть на другой машине.

Comment: Указанная baudrate ком.порта очень низкая (1200 бит/с). Даже один поток на очень слабом железе, способном исполнять Питон код, должен рисовать эти данные быстрее, чем они поступают. Запрос в гугле возвращает [страничку, где данные рисуются с частотой 400Hz](https://taher-zadeh.com/speeding-matplotlib-plotting-times-real-time-monitoring-purposes/), то есть хотя matplotlib не является оптимальным инструментом для отображения данных в реальном времени -- библиотека справляется с работой в данном случае. Правда, код довольно сложен, можно поискать более простые специализированные решения.

Comment: [вот более простой пример отрисовки данных с ком.порта с помощью matplotlib](https://gist.github.com/electronut/d5e5f68c610821e311b0)